# VSCode debugger very slow when evaluating variables

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, .net-core, vscode-debugger

I don't know why my VSCode is extremely slow when I debug a net core Webapi, it takes several seconds to evaluate a line when I press F10 and is very frustrating.
The problem comes when evaluating local variables. If I hide VARIABLES tab in debug section, the debugger improves a lot.

Netcore 2.1
Macbook pro 15" TouchBar.

Comment: Same here, thanks for the tip of hiding the variables tab.

Comment: This is very weird indeed. I experienced the issue when debugging a python application. Closing all tabs also helped.